# Dotliquid not identifying explicitly given null value in a json body

Tags: json, null, liquid, dotliquid

I am working on a JSON transformation using Dotliquid. I want to check if the value of a field is null or not. for example,

```
{
   "Lines": null,
   "Value": "String"
}
```

In my template I want to do the following

```
{% if Lines == null %}
    "Value": "Lines are null"
{% else %}
    "Value": "Lines are not null"
{% endif %}
```

The result I am getting after rendering this is

```
{
  "Value": "Lines are not null"
}
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

When I give the input JSON as

```
{
   "Value": "String"
}
```

Then I am getting the correct result. The problem occurs only when I provide null value explicitly

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help?

[Truthy and Falsey](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/basics/true-and-false)

Try

```
{% if Lines == false %}
    "Value": "Lines are null"
{% else %}
    "Value": "Lines are not null"
{% endif %}
```

I have found the liquid language works best of truth or false

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it cannot return a true because "Lines" is not there to be evaluated.

Perhaps you could try:

```
{% if Lines != null %}
    "Value": "Lines are not null"
{% else %}
    "Value": "Lines are null"
{% endif %}
```